# Rails - Update all records that contain this attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails application, I have a hash that looks like this

```
{"10.70.1.140"=>"e316eba4-5d90-4cd2-a82f-76ca1249153f",
 "10.70.1.2"=>"144efa29-4c59-4cc3-bf12-22715b96dbdf",
 "10.70.0.127"=>"dddec996-c450-4a71-b164-866ae7e7752a",
 "10.70.0.124"=>"5ad9e8f1-6fc7-4f26-83ef-1f0cfec0b568",
 "10.70.0.115"=>"dc3191c1-6235-47ef-a9ab-b1ff735dee6c",
 "10.70.0.161"=>"aa7a96b9-6414-4d0f-90a9-bcc785826c69",
 "10.70.0.2"=>"45d3c462-8300-4111-97bd-1fa4253b3c62",
 "10.70.0.211"=>"5558db58-b373-4007-a855-d568b0bcb106",
 "10.70.0.212"=>"76daaa1f-ee9b-4346-b052-c7ffdaa18838"}
```

The values here are unique identifiers to match records in another table with the corresponding IP address. So what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
Sites.where(node_identifier: hash.values).update_attributes(ip: hash.keys)
```

So that, for example, all issues that have a node identifier of `e316eba4-5d90-4cd2-a82f-76ca1249153f` have their IP address column updated to `10.70.1.140` based on my example here.

However, using the ActiveRecord update command such as what I just demonstrated does not work. I don't get an error or anything, just a huge "UPDATE" statement that does not change anything. How can I do this properly to avoid numerous queries, such as the following example:

```
hash.each do |key, value|
   Sites.where(node_identifier: value).update_all(ip: key)
end
```

I guess another question that stems from this is: Can I update multiple records with multiple keys in one query?

Comment: What SQL is being produced? Because the SQL lines shouldn't exceed the number of key/value pairs in your hash.

Comment: It looks along the lines of:`SQL (94.4ms)  UPDATE `sites` SET `sites`.`ip` = NULL WHERE `sites`.`node_identifier` IN ('e316eba4-5d90-4cd2-a82f-76ca1249153f', '144efa29-4c59-4cc3-bf12-22715b96dbdf'

Comment: You can't do that... You have to iterate through the set and do one update for each.

Comment: Gotcha. Makes sense as to why it wouldn't work then. Thanks so much for the response!

Comment: @RubyRacer I don't think so. I'm pretty sure I did an `update_all` before and also just by reading the [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) documentation it looks perfectly OK.

Comment: @TamerShlash Update all updates all records setting the same value to all records. It doesn't set different values to each record. You CAN'T DO THAT.

Comment: @RubyRacer oh yes, I totally forgot about this, you are correct :)

Comment: @LewlSauce, what's your database?

Comment: @LewlSauce I'm confused. Is your `hash.each` example not working for you? That should correctly produce one SQL query for _each_ key/value pair in your hash.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification. It works but i was just trying to find a way to update it a little faster, perhaps a more efficient way. With the size of the database it takes a good 5-10 seconds to update and I do this quite often.